# Identity theorem in complex analysis

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

The 2nd paragraph of the entry for **Identity theorem** in [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_theorem) states that 
"Thus a holomorphic function is completely determined by its values on a single open neighborhood in D, or even a countable subset of D (provided this contains a converging sequence). This is not true for real-differentiable functions."

What are some examples where it fails to hold in real variable theory ? Also, how can an identity being true for real numbers is true for complex numbers by the identity theorem ? Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 2):

For example, let $f(x)$ be $0$ if $x < 0$ and $e^\frac{-1}{x^2}$ if $x \geqslant 0$, and let $g(x) = 0$. Then $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are both smooth, have the same values on negative half-line, but differ on positive half-line.

Answer (score 0):

There are "bump functions" non zero infinite differentiable functions that are compactly supported (that vanish outside a compact subset).

Answer (score 0):

To give a counterexample with functions differentiable as functions of two real variables, let's first agree that there exist real-valued functions, $f(x,y)$, that are infinitely smooth on the whole $xy$-plane, are $\equiv 1$ in some disc $D$ centered at the origin, and are $\equiv 0$ outside a bigger disc $D'$ centered at the origin.  (Related concept: [mollifiers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mollifier).)  Such a function coincides on $D$ with the function $g \equiv 1$ (the function constantly equal to 1 in the whole $xy$-plane), but is not identical to $g$: they clearly disagree outside of $D'$.

To understand why this fails for two real variables, but holds for the complex variable, the key is the following fact from linear algbera: **a transformation from ${\mathbb R}^2$ to ${\mathbb R}^2$ that is linear over the reals can fail to be linear over the complex numbers if we try to write $(x, y)$ as $x + iy$**.

For a complex-valued function $f(z)$ of a complex variable to be holomorphic at a point $z_{0}$, the total derivative $f'(z_0)$ has to be a linear transformation over the complex scalars, and--according to the boldfaced statement above--this is a much stronger requirement than that $f$ should be differentiable w.r.t. each of: $\Re(z), \Im(z)$.

If we make the variable change
$$
(x, y) \mapsto (z = x + iy, \overline{z} = x - iy),
$$
it can be shown that for a function $f(z)$ of a complex variable to be homolorphic, it is necessary that
$$
{\partial f \over \partial \overline{z}} = 0,
$$
which is just another form of the Cauchy-Riemann equations: see [Theory of analytic functions](https://books.google.com/books/about/Elementary_Theory_of_Analytic_Functions.html?id=KsGbqTBjyoUC).  The latter book also contains a pretty transparent and short proof of what you call the Identity Theorem by using some facts from topology.

Answer (score 0):

If you want an example where the function is a real differentiable function (not necessarily infinitely differentiable) then $f(x)=x^{2}\sin (\frac 1 x)$ for $x \neq 0$, $f(0)=0$ is one such function. Note that $f(\frac 1 {n\pi})=0$ for all $n \in \mathbb N$.